# einen / eins von / der / von den beiden

Tags: word-choice, gender, dative, grammaticality, genitive

Consider the following sentences with two holes:

> Der Titel des ersten Abschnittes dieses Manuskripts ist dem Titel des zweiten Abschnittes viel zu ähnlich. Man sollte ___(A)___   ___(B)___ ändern.

The meaning of the second sentence should be, roughly speaking, "One of these titles should be changed."

Which words would fit at positions (A) and (B)?

**For (A):**

A1. einen

A2. eins

**For (B):**

B1. von beiden

B2. von den beiden

B3. davon

B4. der beiden

B5. der Titel

B6. von Titeln

B7. von den Titeln

Please justify your choices.  References to established sources are overly welcome.

(Remark: no, it's ***NOT*** a homework.)

EDIT: The way it is now (thanks to [Björn Friedrich](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/25241/bj%C3%B6rn-friedrich)!), I'm wondering whether B1-B4 still make it clear that the titles rather than the sections should be changed.

Answer (score 4):

I would write:

> Der Titel des ersten Abschnittes dieses Manuskripts ist dem <s>Titel</s> des zweiten Abschnittes viel zu ähnlich. Man sollte einen der beiden Titel ändern.

- In the first sentence, it is clear that you are talking about *Titel*. Its second mention is redundant, and, therefore, I dropped it.
- In the second sentence, the reference to *Titel* would be clear from the context even without mentioning it there. But if you are emphatic about referring to *Titel*, and not to *Abschnitte*, then simply mention it again.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it should be

> man sollte einen von beiden ändern

This is the most common use I guess.

B6 is wrong, but it would also be correct to use B2 through B7 (except for B6). B5 and B7 are overly redundant, as it is clear that *von (den) beiden* or *davon* refers to the titles.

It is also pretty clear that is must be *einen*, because it is *der/ein Titel*, thus the accusative is *einen Titel*. Omitting *Titel* does not change *einen* to *eins*. *Einen der beiden/einen von den beiden/einen von beiden* is short for *einen Titel der beiden Titel/einen Titel von den beiden Titeln/einen Titel von beiden Titeln*. You're just omitting the nouns here, as the connection is clear.

Comment: I agree, except about B6: The indefinite form of the noun is not correct here.

Comment: @Annatar You are right. I read this wrong.

Comment: @MdAyquassar You *can* say that, but it has a very strong commanding connotation to it. *Einer von beiden sollte geändert werden* is a suggestion. *Einer von beiden ist zu ändern* means *one of them is to be changed* and sounds a bit rude.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out before, the combination of A1 and B1 is the most elegant.

This Wiktionary article lists this combination as a common combination for *beide* and may be used as reference: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/beide